# How to use WorldWind Android app in Offline mode

Tags: android, worldwind

I am using WorldWind map for my android application , its running fine with internet , I want to work map in offline mode , How i can do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Base on this post from their forum (https://forum.worldwindcentral.com/forum/worldwind-android-wwa/android-discussion/17902-android-offline-mode?p=106934#post106934) which is written by a team member of WorldWind, WWA (WorldWindAndroid) does not have an offline capability yet. It is a feature which they are working towards, but it is not clear exactly when it will be implemented.

Here is the related issue on github which no action is done on it: https://github.com/NASAWorldWind/WorldWindAndroid/issues/72